# Matlab Neural Network toolbox

Tags: image-processing, matlab, machine-learning

Is there any way to use as single input an image (256x256 pixels) and get output of single value using Matlab neural network toolbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, import the image to the matlab workspace, divide the image matrix into two dimentional matrices like this:

```
matrix1 = yourimage(:,:,1);
matrix2 = yourimage(:,:,2);
matrix3 = yourimage(:,:,3);
```

each being one colour component-as [`nntool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/nntool.html) works with up to bidimensional matrices- and use them in the `nntool`.